# How to find the asymptotic distribution of an estimator given the mean and variance of an estimator

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, delta-method

I understand that the Delta Method can be used to find asymptotic distribution of estimators.

I have a MLE Estimator with

$ E[\hat\Theta] = \frac{n\Theta_0}{n+1} $

$ Var[\hat\Theta] = \frac{\Theta^2_0}{n(n+2)} $

How can I find the asymptotic distribution of this estimator?

Comment: Related? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2798941/limiting-distribution-of-mle-for-uniform-distribution

Comment: Is this the only available information? You can only say $E[\hat\theta]\to \theta_0$ and $Var[\hat\theta]\to 0$, so $\hat\theta$ converges in probability (and hence in distribution) to $\theta_0$. This of course gives a degenerate asymptotic distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem provides this info as the mean and variance of MLE of a uniform distribution over [0,$\Theta$]. The problem then asks for an asymptotic distribution for such a MLE estimator.

Comment: In that case see https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/130447/119261 for the non-degenerate asymptotic distribution.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/96689/28746

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to stack exchange.

The delta method does not have anything to do with your question.

Maximum likelihood estimators are, under some regularity conditions, asymptically normally distributed.

The delta method is a way of finding the asymptotic distribution of a (differentiable) function of a random variable that is itself asymptotically normal.